# Journey Builder and relative dates criteria

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, marketing-cloud-connect

Is there any way on Journey Builder to use Date fields and relative dates? It seems that we can only select a specific date (is equal/after/before `MM/DD/YYYY`).

I would like to create a Salesforce Data Event and being able to use a date field and filter the contact as follows:

`Date equals TODAY + 10 days`

Comment: It seems that you can't use this feature when using Salesforce Data Event as an entry source. I've tried to use it too but without sucess..

Comment: Thank you @RachidMamai. Is there any workaround ? We tried the salesforce data event then a Wait 10 days activity and then a SMS send, but it didn't work very well... It was sent 1 hour before the right time (we checked the time zone in SFMC and SF, it was the same timezone for both users... so we didn't understand the delay...), and every contacts who meet the criteria are injected into the Journey et received the message, even the ones created in less than 10 days, which was not OK for us...!